# Confused about CMD/ENTRYPOINT in Dockerfile

Tags: mongodb, docker, dockerfile

I am unsure what to use for `ENTRYPOINT` vs `CMD` for my `Dockerfile` below.

```
FROM mongo:3.4-xenial

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN apt-get install zip \
    unzip
RUN apt-get install -y default-jdk
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get clean

RUN mkdir -p /opt/project

COPY ./project-repo/target/project-repo.zip /opt/project

WORKDIR /opt/project 
RUN unzip project-repo.zip

ENTRYPOINT echo '#!/bin/bash\n\
    pidfile="${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/docker-entrypoint-temp-mongod.pid" \n\
    rm -f "$pidfile" \n\
    # start MongoDB here \n\
    mongod --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log --dbpath /data/db/ --fork --pidfilepath "$pidfile" \n\
    mongo=( mongo --host 127.0.0.1 --port 27017 --quiet ) \n\
    # check to see that our "mongod" actually did start up (catches "--help", "--version", MongoDB 3.2 being silly, slow prealloc, etc) \n\
    # https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-16292 \n\
    tries=30 \n\
    while true; do \n\
        if ! { [ -s "$pidfile" ] && ps "$(< "$pidfile")" &> /dev/null; }; then \n\
            # bail ASAP if "mongod" is not even running \n\
            echo >&2 \n\
            echo >&2 "error: mongod does not appear to have stayed running -- perhaps it had an error?" \n\
            echo >&2 \n\
            exit 1 \n\
        fi \n\
        if mongo admin --eval "quit(0)" &> /dev/null; then \n\
            # success! \n\
            break \n\
        fi \n\
        (( tries-- )) \n\
        if [ "$tries" -le 0 ]; then \n\
            echo >&2 \n\
            echo >&2 "error: mongod does not appear to have accepted connections quickly enough -- perhaps it had an error?" \n\
            echo >&2 \n\
            exit 1 \n\
        fi \n\
        sleep 1 \n\
    done \n\
    mongo -- admin <<-EOF \n\
    db.createUser({user:"user", pwd:"admin123", roles:[{role:"root", db:"admin"}]}); \n\
EOF' >> ./init_mongo.sh && chmod +x ./init_mongo.sh && ./init_mongo.sh && \
    chmod +x /opt/project/setup.sh && /opt/project/setup.sh all && \
    chmod +x /opt/project/start.sh && /opt/project/start.sh all

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["echo 'Welcome to Demo'"]
```

My MongoDB initialization is based on the one supplied with the standard image. They use `mongod` as the `CMD`.

I need a few things - start mongo, create the user then run my scripts - setup and start.

There are no errors. However, after `ENTRYPOINT` finishes doing its' thing, the container just exits. I want it to stay running!!!

My guess that my `CMD` is wrong. Please advise.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> After `ENTRYPOINT` finishes doing it’s thing, the container just exits.

This is a universal truth: the lifetime of a container is exactly the lifetime of the `ENTRYPOINT`, or absent one, the `CMD`.

In terms of style, don’t try writing very long scripts like that inline in a Dockerfile.  Make it be a separate file, `COPY` it into the image, make sure it’s executable, and just run it directly.

The other style point is that it’s very useful to get a debugging shell in a built image like

```
docker run --rm -it imagename bash
```

But, that form only overwrites the `CMD`.  That means you should generally put the command you want to run in `CMD` exclusively.  Since this will be the main container process, it must be something that stays running for as long as the container will be; it can’t be something like `start.sh` or `service start` that tries to launch it in the background and immediately returns.  For example,

```
CMD ["/opt/project/myservice", "--foreground"]
```

What good is `ENTRYPOINT`, then?  If you have both `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`, the `ENTRYPOINT` will get run with the `CMD` as command-line arguments.  A very common pattern is to write a script that does some initial setup, then does `exec "$@"` to run the command part.  From your example,

```
#!/bin/sh
./init_mongo.sh
exec "$@"
```

And your combined Dockerfile could look more or less like

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
# ... other setup bits ...
WORKDIR /opt/project
COPY entrypoint.sh init_mongo.sh .
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh init_mongo.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/project/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["/opt/project/myservice", "--foreground"]
```

Comment: I tried `CMD exec /bin/bash -c "trap : TERM INT; sleep infinity & wait"` from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57891045/confused-about-cmd-entrypoint-in-dockerfile/57891381#57891381 and it did nothing for me. The container still exits and there is nothing in the logs.

Comment: Why do you want a container that just sleeps forever?  Start your actual service as a foreground process.  (Tip: `CMD foo bar` is implicitly wrapped in a `sh -c` and you don’t need to include that yourself.)

Comment: I am acting in a "DevOps" capacity, if you will... this project has a bunch of services. The project has been around for a while, and I am not one of the developers. I want the entire thing to run under docker. My problem is the container process with PID 1, if I understand this issue correctly. If `sleep infinity` worked, my other processes, started via `ENTRYPOINT` would continue running in the background. Would they not? If that is the case, I just need to figure to how to make the foreground running. Why won't: `#!/bin/bash\n while true; do echo 'Hit CTRL+C'; sleep 10; done` and such work?

Comment: Generally you'd run one service per container.  If you can split them into separate images that can be easier to maintain sometimes, but even if not, it's easy enough to run multiple containers off the same image with different commands for the main process.